# Set marker with place name in google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am getting the place name of google maps using

```
  Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(MainActivity.this, data);
  Logger.e("The ", "Place: " + place.getName());
```

now i want to set the marker at this place name. How can I acheive this?

Comment: Please read the document and API- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker#customize_the_marker_image

Answer (score 0):

First try to get the latitude and longitude from place name using [Geocoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) after that try following code for showing the marker on the map.

```
 GoogleMap map;
    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(placelatitude, placeLongitude))
            .title("Place Name"));
```